# $L_1$-subspace of the predual of a von Neumann algebra

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, von-neumann-algebras

If $M$ is a type $II$ von Neumann algebra, then the predual has a complemented subspace isometric to $L_1(0,1)$. It follows from the existence of expectation. However, I don't know whether such a result holds true for type $III$ von Neumann algebras. My question is, for a type $III$ von Neumann algebra $M$, does the predual $M_*$ have a subspace isometric to $L_1(0,1)$? If it is true, any references?

Comment: Yes. Connes and Stormer have proved that any non type I factor with separable predual contains a hyperfinite II_1 factor with a normal conditional expectation onto it (modulo Takesaki's conditional expectation theorem). https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=470689 This handles the case of a general von Neumann algebra with an atomic center. The case of diffuse center is easy.

Comment: @NarutakaOZAWA Thank you so much!!! However, what do you mean by the 'diffuse' case is easy? Do you mean using the direct integral? In this case, we will need the Hilbert space to be separable.

Comment: There's always a normal conditional expectation onto the center.

Comment: @NarutakaOZAWA Right. So, there exists a normal conditional expectation from M onto L∞(0,1). However, I do not follow why this will give me ``L1 is a subspace of M∗''. What did I miss? It seems that p.978 observation 3 in https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1112/plms/pdt006 gives me what I wanted. However, do you have a more fundamental reference or argument

Comment: I see it from https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2045010.pdf?refreqid=excelsior%3A66ad602731978ebdc3ec773f644ef6e9&ab_segments=&origin=